# Merge data frames and replace NONE with values in R

Tags: r

I have two data.frames:

```
data.frame1:
CustID  FirstName   LastName    Address         DOB         City    Phone
132    Mary         K               999 Drive   1/1/2011    Chicago 888-0000
133    Mona         J               222 Road    1/4/2002    NY      999-8888
188    Jack         S               122 Street  9/2/2009    Washin  777-9999
None    Helen       L               111 Rd      1/4/2010        
None    John        M               888 Lane    4/2/2002        
None    Sally       K               222 Street  2/3/2002        


data.frame2                     
CustID FirstName LastName Address   DOB         City
132    Mary      K        999 Drive 1/1/2011    Chicago 
133    Mona      J         222 Road 1/4/2002    NY  
188    Jack      S      122 Street  9/2/2009    Washington  
3338    Helen   L         111 Rd    1/4/2010        
882     John    M       888 Lane    4/2/2002        
976    Sally    K     222 Street    2/3/2002
```

Data.frame1 contains None in CustID column. I need to replace these Nones with a CustID from data.frame2 and make sure that columns FirstName, LastName, Address, DOB match from both data sets, because some names can match from both data sets but have different address and DOB - these are not the same people. 
I have converted these columns into character from factor (not sure if it matters), and applied match() function but received 0 matches (which i know is wrong)
this is my code:

```
data.frame1$ID[match(c(data.framr2$'FirstName',
                     data.frame2$'LastName',
                     data.frame2$'DOB',
                     data.frame2$'Address'), 
                     c(data.frame1$'FirstName',
                     data.frame1$'LastName',
                     data.frame1$'DOB',
                     data.frame1$'Address'))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `dplyr`.

```
  library(dplyr)

  df1 <- read.table(text = 
       "CustID  FirstName   LastName    Address         DOB         City    Phone
  132    Mary         K               999Drive   1/1/2011    Chicago 888-0000
  133    Mona         J               222Road    1/4/2002    NY      999-8888
  188    Jack         S               122Street  9/2/2009    Washin  777-9999
  None    Helen       L               111Rd      1/4/2010     ''     ''
  None    John        M               888Lane    4/2/2002       ''   ''
  None    Sally       K               222Street  2/3/2002        ''  ''"
  , header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)


  df2 <- read.table(text=                    
  "CustID FirstName LastName Address   DOB         City
  132    Mary      K        999Drive 1/1/2011    Chicago 
  133    Mona      J         222Road 1/4/2002    NY  
  188    Jack      S      122Street  9/2/2009    Washington  
  3338    Helen   L         111Rd    1/4/2010     ''   
  882     John    M       888Lane    4/2/2002       '' 
  976    Sally    K     222Street    2/3/2002    ''"
  , header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

  df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% select(-City), by = c('FirstName', 'LastName', 'DOB', 'Address')) %>% 
       mutate(CustID = ifelse(CustID.y == "None", CustID.x, CustID.y)) %>% select(-CustID.x, -CustID.y)



        FirstName LastName   Address      DOB    City    Phone CustID
1      Mary        K  999Drive 1/1/2011 Chicago 888-0000    132
2      Mona        J   222Road 1/4/2002      NY 999-8888    133
3      Jack        S 122Street 9/2/2009  Washin 777-9999    188
4     Helen        L     111Rd 1/4/2010                    3338
5      John        M   888Lane 4/2/2002                     882
6     Sally        K 222Street 2/3/2002                     976
```

Comment: TBT8, it looks like you joined table2 with table1 - so if i need to do the other way around since I am pulling data from tabel 2 into table 1?

Answer (score 1):

This code should illustrate how you have to proceed:

- merge the data.frames by "fname" and "lname" (consider only the rows where id is missing)
- select the "id" column of the merged data.frame and copy it to df1

Example

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(NA, 12, NA, 13), 
    fname=c("A","B","Z","D"), 
    lname=c("1","2","3","4"))

df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1, 21, 33, 44), 
    fname=c("Z","A","A","Z")  , 
    lname=c("1","3","1","3"))

df1[!complete.cases(df1),1] <- merge(
    x=df1[!complete.cases(df1[,"id"]),], 
    y=df2, 
    by=c("fname", "lname"))[,"id.y"]
```

Comment: I tried your code, aivanov, but received the error message: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, !complete.cases(df1), 3, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has length zero

Comment: I fixed one bug about 20 minutes ago, have you checked the most recent version?

Comment: aivanov, I got this error message - any idea how to overcome it: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, !complete.cases(df1), 3, value = c(4897941,  : 
  replacement has 7041 rows, data has 3837   It is true that 2 data frames have dif number of rows